# Microsoft Flow - Sharepoint 'When a file is created' triggers on subfolders

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have created a Microsoft Flow which triggers with a SharePoint  "When A file is created (properties only) trigger. In this Flow I will then create 2 new default subfolders for the folder which made the trigger to execute.

The trigger executes on the creation of the folder in my path. However it also triggers again for both subfolders and thus generating an infinite loop. 
According to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#GetOnNewFileItems) I should define `Folder` to execute only on this folder. As seen in below picture.

[image: Configuration]

Anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong or how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the trigger, add a "Get file metadata" action:
[image]

For the file identifier, use the Id from the trigger
[image]

This will then give you a property "IsFolder", which will allow you to then have an if whether it is a file or folder:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But then I will keep the solution I have at the moment, where I have the trigger "When a file is created" and check if `File name` and `File name with extension` are equal, if so then I also know it is a folder.
I was just wondering if there was a cleaner solution which did not trigger my Workflow 5 times everytime. While only 1 time it really does something.